# Can we use Odin/Heimdall to emulate a fake flash (without real hardware connection)?

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, unbricking, odin, heimdall

As my title suggests.. is there a method to flash a (samsung) firmware on a formatted sd card (fat32 I guess? And 16gb too?) instead of an actual phone (flash emulation) using pit file in heimdall/odin or changing values in heimdall/odin to make it happen?

What I want to do : **Just partition and flash the bootloader and kernel partitions to an sd card (it should be partitioned in a similar way as it happens after flashing them on internal memory normally through odin.. problem is .. phone is deadboot i.e can't go in download mode and I want to get the correct bootloader and primary partitions on the sd card and try to boot through it in download mode and reflash normally..)**

I have firmware but I cannot seem to get it flashed (or in other words, partitioned according to pit file) on an sd card without actual working phone sadly. I tried and researched a lot but couldn't find exact answer.

*Furthermore, repairing in a local shop or a box isn't an option. And can't afford replacing motherboard etc. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !*

Comment: not possible. Odin is for communication with phone in download mode (proprietary protocol). there are several partitions (some ext4, some just binaries) the fat32 doesn't matter. besides one can't boot bootloader from sd slot, the whole idea is pointless. only the ROM can mounted from sd card, but that requires modified ROM or heavily modified kernel, a lot of knowledge and unlocked bootloader (and OEM unlocking requires fully working android)

Comment: buy JIG dongle to enter download mode and flash official stock ROM+bootloader+firmware+CSC from Odin it will do the proper partitioning itself https://www.xda-developers.com/samloader-download-updates-samsung-galaxy

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah I guess its like that and probably that's why there's nothing on web about this. But, have you came across something like dead boot repair ? Its mentioned to work for samsung devices too..

Comment: Also jig won't work as phone's bootloader has been corrupted (or am I wrong?)

Comment: you try and tell us